# JS/jQuery - rearranging an HTML table element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table on my site and it is too long across for mobile so am trying to invert it so that it is like:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
```

instead of like:

```
1 2 3 4
a b c d
```

```js
$("#table").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var newrows = [];
  $this.find("tr").each(function(){
    var i = 0;
    $(this).find("td").each(function(){
      i++;
      if(newrows[i] === undefined) { newrows[i] = $("<tr></tr>"); }
      newrows[i].append($(this));
    });
  });
  $this.find("tr").remove();
  $.each(newrows, function(){
    $this.append(this);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>b</td>
  <td>c</td>
  <td>d</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I found this function and it works fine in some cases but not all (of course, typically, it works fine in this snippet) but on other devices I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined
    at Function.oe.contains (jquery.js:2)
    at xe (jquery.js:2)
    at Re (jquery.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.append (jquery.js:2)
    at script.js:35
    at Function.each (jquery.js:2)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (script.js:34)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (script.js:22)
```

Lines 34+35 from this error refers to:

```
$.each(newrows, function(){
  $this.append(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was caused by an empty array element.

I changed this:

```
$(this).find("td").each(function(){
  i++;
  if(newrows[i] === undefined) { newrows[i] = $("<tr></tr>"); }
  newrows[i].append($(this));
});
```

To this:

```
$(this).find("td").each(function(){
  if(newrows[i] === undefined) { newrows[i] = $("<tr></tr>"); }
  newrows[i].append($(this));
  i++;
});
```

And now it seems to be working fine across devices